Broken trajectory in Calculus of Variations (Weierstrass–Erdmann condition)
We wish to determine the extremals of the following functional:
$$\int_0^1 (x'(t)^2 -1)^2 \; dt$$ with conditions $x(0) =0, x(1)=0$.
There is the trivial solution $x(t) =0$. We wish to study the other solutions to the problem. In particular, we are interested in determining if there are any broken extremals (that is, with corners). We solved the Euler-Lagrange equation, which yields:
\begin{align*}
    F_x - \frac{d}{dt} F_{x'} &= 0 \\
      x''(3 (x')^2 -1) &= 0
\end{align*}
The non-trivial solutions take the form:
$$
x(t) = \pm \sqrt{\frac{1}{3}}t + k 
$$
which do not satisfy the border conditions. Therefore, we look for a broken trajectory.
How do we determine exactly where the corner will be? Is it determined simultaneously along with each ``branch'' in $x(t)$? Do we guess and later check whether the Weierstrass-Erdmann conditions hold?
\begin{align*}
    &\left[F - x' F_{x'}  \right] \Big{|}_{t = c^-} =\left[F - x' F_{x'}  \right] \Big{|}_{t = c^+}  \\
   &F_{x'} \Big{|}_{t = c^-} =F_{x'} \Big{|}_{t = c^+} 
\end{align*}

Hint: Consider to double-check your solution (v1).
